# meaning of "head over to"

Tags: subcontinental-english

what is the meaning of "head over to"

I was reading one blog. In that blog, they said like if you want more informatio
please "head over to this link"

Comment: "Go to this link."

Answer (score 1):

*To head* is to move in a particular direction. This is in most dictionaries, *eg* [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/head_42):

> [INTRANSITIVE] to go in a particular direction
>
> **be headed**: *Where are you headed?*
>
> **head for/towards/through etc**: *We decided to head for home.
> She headed towards the library.*
>
> **head north/south/east/west**: *They
> headed north, across the desert.*

This is just an extension of that use: go to this link.

Comment: According to etymonline.com, the connection is through the sense "turn one's head in a given direction," and dates to the early 17th century.